# Not able to set Interactive Push Notifications on iOS8

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I was already able to set Interactive LOCAL notifications, but the Remote notifications aren't working. I'm using Parse.com to send the JSON

My AppDelegate.Swift looks like this:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  SwifferApp
//
//  Created by Training on 29/06/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Training. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        Parse.setApplicationId("eUEC7O4Jad0Kt3orqRouU0OJhkGuE20n4uSfrLYE", clientKey: "WypmaQ8XyqH26AeWIANttqwUjRJR4CIM55ioXvez")

        let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData!) {
        let currentInstallation:PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError!) {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:NSDictionary!) {

        var notification:NSDictionary = userInfo.objectForKey("aps") as NSDictionary

        if notification.objectForKey("content-available"){
            if notification.objectForKey("content-available").isEqualToNumber(1){
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadTimeline", object: nil)
            }
        }else{
            PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        }
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}
```

on Parse, I'm setting the Push payload like this:

```
{
"alert": "Tune in for the World Series, tonight at 8pm EDT",
"badge": "Increment",
"sound": "chime",
"category": "FIRST_CATEGORY"
}
```

and I receive the push, but not with the custom buttons I've set.

Comment: I'm not clear on what is not working for you. Does didReceiveRemoteNotification get called or not?

Comment: Yes. The push is working and appearing, but the interactive buttons arent working. I think there's something related to the category

Comment: @Nick : Do you found any solution how we can show interactive buttons when receives a notification?

Comment: @RayofHope check out this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh3lLpV1k_Y I followed it to make it work. And you just need to add "category" in your remote notification payload in order to make remote notification show interactive buttons too (check my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass categories while registering for APNS.

Look at my sample :

```
   var replyAction : UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    replyAction.identifier = "REPLY_ACTION"
    replyAction.title = "Yes, I need!"

    replyAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    replyAction.authenticationRequired = false

    var replyCategory : UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    replyCategory.identifier = "REPLY_CATEGORY"

    let replyActions:NSArray = [replyAction]

    replyCategory.setActions(replyActions, forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    replyCategory.setActions(replyActions, forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)

    let categories = NSSet(object: replyCategory)



    let settings : UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: settings, categories: categories))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if my problem is the same to yours (Make sure your problem is not due to Parse). Just post my solution here in case anyone else would encounter the same issue.

My problem is in the notification category.

Make sure you have set the category when registering the notification settings (I'm using Objective-C, no much difference):

```
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *notificationCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
            notificationCategory.identifier = @"CallNotificationCategory";
            [notificationCategory setActions:@[declineAction, answerAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

            NSSet *categories = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:notificationCategory, nil];
```

And, when you send remote notification, make sure you have "category" in the payload and the value is the same as you defined in the client. In my case it's something like:

```
{
  "alert": "Tune in for the World Series, tonight at 8pm EDT",
  "badge": "Increment",
  "sound": "chime",
  "category": "CallNotificationCategory"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is in case if anyone comes across this problem while using **Firebase Remote Notifications.**

Just ask the backend developer to send:

```
"notification" : {
  "title" : YOUR_TITLE,
  "body" : YOUR_BODY,
  "click_action" : YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get interactive push notifications displaying and working in Swift with Parse. Note that you need to create a `UIMutableNotificationAction` for each interactive button you want to create. Source below goes into much more detail of configuring options for buttons.

In your app delegate file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

    var notificationActionAccept :UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    notificationActionAccept.identifier = "ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER"
    notificationActionAccept.title = "Accept"
    notificationActionAccept.destructive = true
    notificationActionAccept.authenticationRequired = false
    notificationActionAccept.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background

    var notificationCategory:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    notificationCategory.identifier = "CallNotificationCategory"
    notificationCategory .setActions([notificationActionAccept], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)

    let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: NSSet(array:[notificationCategory]))
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    return true
}
```

And in Parse Cloud when you send the push, you would match the `category` to the `UIMutableUserNotificationCategory` like @Xialin mentioned above.

Looks like you weren't setting categories or at least not setting them until after you had registered the `UINotificationSettings` - you need to set them before or it won't work.

I got most of this info at the link below. It goes into more detail if needed. Hope this helps:

http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/90742435155/notifications-in-ios-8-part-2-using-swift-what-is