# iOS8 - Silent push notifications doesn't work until add "sound" attribute in payload

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an application with Push notifications enabled.I add background modes, add logic for registration for both iOS versions and they should work equally.
In iOS7 this works as expected (Application "wake up" and fetch data):

```
"customJson":{ },
"aps":{"content-available":1}
```

In iOS8 to do the same thing I have to add empty sound,otherwise didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: method is not executed:

```
"customJson":{ },
"aps":{"content-available":1,sound:""}
```

For registration I use  workaround  from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049266/get-the-push-notification-list-on-ios8) question.
Why this happen,any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem before, seems like this is a bug with silent push notifications. I added

```
sound:""
```

like you did and it worked.

What I've learned is, that silent notifications will not be handled by the system when the user fore-quit'ed the app (killed via swipe on task manager):
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
So if the user killed the app, it shouldn't do anything in the background anymore. This makes sense from a user's perspective.

Comment: Thanks for response.In first days of iOS7 I learned about force quit of app, so this is expected for me.In iOS8 documentation this is fixed alread.I'm just curious why I need to add "sound" attribute.

Comment: @Foriger: i think the logical answer to that question is, as per (http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/troubleshooting/ios-background-push.html):

"Background pushes require the same notification settings as a standard push. Even if you’re sending a “silent” push, a push with no alert, badge, or sound, the application notification settings must have one of the following enabled:

Alert Style - Banner or Alerts selected
Badge App Icon enabled
Sounds enabled"

While i don't agree with the logic if this is true, as "content-available":1 should circumvent this, it might yet still be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding remote-notification to Info.plist UIBackgroundModes array?
You need to have that entry for silent notifications to work.

Comment: It's added when project is created, so this is not a case.