# Which xcode to be used to upload new version on iTunes compatible with iOS 8?

Tags: xcode, ios8, app-store-connect

I have to upload newer version of my app which is compatible to iOS 8. 
When I am uploading the app from Xcode 6.1 (Not Beta) I am getting following error

> Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 or later SDK.

and when I am uploading the app with XCode 5.1.1 I am not able to use the following code for Push Notification.

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to be compiled with iOS7 and build with xcode 5 so you cannot use new API's that are only available in iOS8.

you need to use this code:

```
    // changes of API in iOS 8.0
- (void) registerForPushNotification
{
    NSLog(@"registerForPushNotification");
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_8_0 //__IPHONE_8_0 is not defined in old xcode (==0). The use 80000

        NSLog(@"registerForPushNotification: For iOS >= 8.0");

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                              categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
#endif
    } else {
        NSLog(@"registerForPushNotification: For iOS < 8.0");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
}
```

more info here:[iOS 8 enabled device not receiving PUSH notifications after code update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909568/ios-8-enabled-device-not-receiving-push-notifications-after-code-update)

Comment: But I am getting compile time error for "registerUserNotificationSettings". How can I create a build?

Comment: The "registerUserNotificationSettings" is not available in iOS7.
Replace your code for this code:
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

Comment: They will work fine, beacause when you use xcode 5 the application will be compiled with iOS7

Comment: No it won't because iOS7 SDK doesn't know about "registerUserNotificationSettings". I tried that already

Comment: I think you didnt understand me.

Replace this code:
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

for this:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to open and run the project once in xcode 6 to ensure iPhone 6/6+ and iOS 8 support. Then upload via xcode.

Comment: See this in my question
""When I am uploading the app from Xcode 6.1 (Not Beta) I am getting following error""

Comment: Oh obviously misunderstood your question, my bad. sorry but I don't know the answer then. Good luck anyways!

Comment: No problem and thanks for trying. I have uploaded the build with XCode 6.0.1.