# How to get data using silent remote notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am sending my app a silent remote notification.

This is my payload:

```
{"aps":{"content-available":1},"SUCCESS":"YES"}
```

I have set the **"Required background modes"** with:

```
"App downloads content from the network"
"App downloads content in response to push notifications"
```

And after a few minutes the method **application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler** is called but I can't find the data i'm sending in my payload.

Also, I figured the method **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler** should be called as well but it isn't.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I have it as well, also doesn't work. It's not the solution.

Comment: Have you check all certificates and process on server side?

Comment: Yes. Currently working on development certificate.

Comment: Generally, this happens if you there are certain http ports to be opened. So check that as well.

Comment: Dont know what that means...

Comment: Are you running on ios8?  Have you used the new registration method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909568/ios-8-enabled-device-not-receiving-push-notifications-after-code-update

Comment: Not running on iOS 8 but indeed using the new registration for those who will

Comment: Ok. I just tried a test app and as long as I used the new registration methods I received the user info dictionary in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`

Comment: I have tried using the methods in the link you attached but still no luck