# iOS Push Notifications Working on iOS 8 But Not on iOS 7 in iOS SDK 8.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, push-notification

```
if([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) { 

         [self registerForiOS8PushSettings]; //for iOS8  

    } else {
//iOS7 or earlier

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    }
```

Unable to get the push notification to iOS7 device. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificatiosnWithDeviceToken` get called, In fact Message is successfully delivered. Working fine in iOS8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 enabled device not receiving PUSH notifications after code update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909568/ios-8-enabled-device-not-receiving-push-notifications-after-code-update)

Answer (score 1):

With the iOS8 the process had change. To make your app register for iOS8 and early versions make something like this:

```
-(void)registerAppForNotifications{

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

}
```