# Push Notification Not delivered in IOS8.1 but working fine in less then that

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

**UPDATE: note i was using Xcode 6.01 and deploy using this code,which not working,but when i install Xcode 6.1 version and deployed the code it works...so its may be Xcode version issue my be it will help others.**

i am using following code for push notification using PARSE.com it works fine in all device below ios8,

```
if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.
        BOOL preBackgroundPush = ![application respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];
        BOOL oldPushHandlerOnly = ![self respondsToSelector:@selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)];
        BOOL noPushPayload = ![launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
        }
    }
```

Also i test with these condition (works fine with less then ios 8

## if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else
```

## endif

```
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

even [iOS 8 enabled device not receiving PUSH notifications after code update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909568/ios-8-enabled-device-not-receiving-push-notifications-after-code-update) not work for me
I set notification correctly and my bundle identifier set is correct too

Comment: Are you getting device token?

Comment: Yes even in parse.com i get that push is delivering,but in IOS 8.1 in my device (iPhone/ipad both) i got no notification

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: I think this link will help you more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909568/ios-8-enabled-device-not-receiving-push-notifications-after-code-update