# Push Notification In IOS8

Tags: ios

Does Apple has introduced any real time fast instant push notification in iOS recently which will improve user experience for the app? Please suggest some answers as I am going to use Push Notification in my app?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. I suggest you to post it there http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you want to send push notification to other users of app ? This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909568/ios-8-enabled-device-not-receiving-push-notifications-after-code-update

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at using [Parse](https://parse.com/).

There's a link to the push notification documentation [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS).

It's pretty straightforward to get working, and the documentation provides support for both Objective C and Swift. Hope this helps!