# What is difference between Push Notification in iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Tags: ios, push-notification

Can you tell me the Difference between Push notification in IOS 7 and IOS 8, What is the new methods in IOS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this on `.m` file:

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
```

Then in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function:

```
    if(IS_IOS_8_OR_LATER) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
    //register to receive notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

And now only for iOS 8:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:   (UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString   *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif
```

And then the delegate methods.

Taken from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909568/ios-8-enabled-device-not-receiving-push-notifications-after-code-update). This answer helped me with this.
Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work for push notification in *iOS 6,7,8* in all cases then use the following code snippet inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vist following link, could be useful

http://corinnekrych.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-support-push-notification-for.html

Answer (score 0):

For new in `iOS` `notification` you can check out `WWDC 2014` `session 713` on this -

http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/713xx1il4h4ur9c/713/713_hd_whats_new_in_ios_notifications.mov?dl=1

You can also download PDF file -

http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/713xx1il4h4ur9c/713/713_whats_new_in_ios_notifications.pdf?dl=1