# Firebase push notification not working in iOS8 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Xcode 8.2.1. I integrated Firebase to my iOS app. In iOS9 and iOS10 devices I am getting push notifications alert getting properly. But in iOS8 device I did not get push notification alert. I got device token in iOS 8 devices, but push notification not working. Please go through the following code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max)
{
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
    // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
    UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
    | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
    | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];

    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
    [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
}

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
  [FIRApp configure];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
        [self parsePushNoticationResponse:userInfo];
    }
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
        [self parsePushNoticationResponse:userInfo];
        //completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
    }
}
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
        [self parsePushNoticationResponse:userInfo];
        //completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
    }
}
```

How to solve the issue? Please help me.

Comment: Notification setting is different for iOS 8 & 9. Did you set for iOS 8 too. I can't see in your code

Comment: where I can set notification setting for iOS8?

Comment: look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909568/ios-8-enabled-device-not-receiving-push-notifications-after-code-update